# Firefox input can't scroll when text is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a input which is selected on click:

```
<input onClick="this.select();" type="text" name="country" value="Norwayasdasdasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" readonly><br>
```

The problem is that, in Firefox, the first time I can scroll to the right by holding the left mouse button. Then, I can't do it for the second time. When I want to scroll to see the full value for the second time, the whole text is selected and I can't scroll anymore. I don't have this issue in Chrome.

Please help!

Thanks,
Quincy

Comment: You don't want to remove the `onclick="this.select()"`? You can scroll with the keyboard though. Home, End etc.

Comment: I need to keep that feature, however; it is required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make the click a toggle, by remembering if the text was selected the last time you clicked. So add a variable

```javascript
var selection = false;
```

and change the onclick handler to

```javascript
if (selection = !selection) this.select();
```

Then the first slick will select all the text, the next click will deselect it, etc. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gvko38h6/1/).

---

Edit: an alternative method is to deselect the text on a mousedown. That would be closer to what you need.

```html
<input onMouseDown="this.setSelectionRange(0,0)" onClick="this.select();"
type="text" name="country"
value="Norwayasdasdasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" readonly>
```

See [other JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gvko38h6/2/).

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to deselect in for the next time.

Comment: This is so nice! Thanks! Do you if it is a firefox bug?

Comment: It's not really a bug. The default action in Firefox when you move the mouse on a selected piece of text is to invoke drag-and-drop instead of selecting again. So basically what you're doing is attempting to move the whole text somewhere else.

Comment: I like your solution better since it only deselects on a mousedown event otherwise if you happen to put your mouse over it the test is unselected

Comment: This behaviour isn't only related to Firefox, it seems related to all GTK applications. (GTK is a library to build graphical user interfaces)

Comment: @RobotMan Ah. Do you know if it's possible to switch this on or off? I tried looking in Firefox's about:config for an option, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @MrLister I think Firefox hasn't an option to change this behaviour. More generally, for all GTK based applications I think that if you want change this behaviour you must edit the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fix the problem with this workaround:

```
<input onmouseout="var tmp=this.value;this.value='';this.value=tmp" onClick="this.select();" type="text" name="country" value="Norwayasdasdasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" readonly><br>
```

So, when the mouse exit from input area the text is rewritten (this hack remove the selection from the text).
If you want keep the text selected when mouse exit from input area, you can use `onmouseenter` rather than `onmouseout`

Comment: Thanks, your method works! I want to know is this a firefox bug?

Comment: How is this the solution? It deselects the text whenever you move the mouse out of the input.

Comment: The solution is really nice and it works well! Thanks!